# I need to split data in a csv database using pandas in python and write it to and xlsx file with multiple sheets as well as creating an additional col

Tags: python, pandas, export, calculated-columns, data-conversion

I have a database (Accessable: https://datacatalog.worldbank.org/search/dataset/0041443/World---Global-Tracking-Framework , download "Renewable Energy Indicator Results" CSV file) that i need to work with and manipulate. The aim is to import into python with pandas the database, remove 2 columns, add and additional column at the end with the contents being an average amount of the 24 years of data collect (1990-2014). After this all has been done, the first column should be the series name consisting of ['Total final energy consumption (TFEC) (TJ)', 'Renewable energy share of TFEC (%)', 'Renewable energy consumption (TJ)', 'Renewable electricity share of total electricity output (%)', 'Total electricity output (GWh)', 'Renewable electricity output (GWh)'], the country names and then the data of the years 1990-2014 and the average. The issue i am having is that the data is split twice by columns, first by series name and then by country. I would like to output this data into an xlsx file where the excel file has 6 sheets, each sheet containing the data relative to the series name. ie one sheet for Total final energy consumption (TFEC) (TJ) where the first column is the countries names and then the data of the years after that, and then the same for the other series.

I am new to coding and finding it difficult to find solutions to the issue so far. below is the code i have been able to come up with so far. PS im using jupyter notebook to code with.

```
1: import pandas as pd
2: df = pd.read_csv('gtfrenewableenergydata.csv')
3: df.drop(['Series Code', 'Country Code'], inplace=True, axis=1)
4: df.insert(27,"Total Average",df.mean(axis=1))
5: my_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('ExcelProject.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
6: df.to_excel(my_writer, sheet_name = 'Renewable Energy Project', index = False)
7: my_writer.save()
```

I know at line 4: the code is incorrect as the new column is producing NaN and not the average of the 24 years. I also have no code at all in splitting the data into multiple sheets as i cannot figure that one out yet.

ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED!!

Answer (score 0):

For the excel file, you would do this to write to multiple sheets. This assumes that `Total final energy consumption (TFEC) (TJ)` is the column  you want to split by to get separate sheets.

```
my_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('ExcelProject.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
for key,g in df.groupby('Total final energy consumption (TFEC) (TJ)'):    
   g.to_excel(my_writer, sheet_name=key, index=False, header=True)
```